# How To Hide Strings Inside DLL File While Compiling?

Tags: c++, string, encryption, dll

I'm using the XorString class (with FORCEINLINE constructor) to hide strings like "How are you?" but I can still see strings like

```
c : \ u s e r s \ h a t t r i c k \ s o u r c e \ r e p o s \ h k . s k i n s \ d e p s \ j s o n \ s r c \ d e t a i l / s e r i a l i z e r . h p p
```

even while they are not declared in any header or source files, inside the DLL. Is there a VS project option (C/ C++ or Linker) that can hide these? Thanks!

Comment: Probably related to debug information.

Comment: More specific please, if you know? I set Linker's options NOT to generate any Manifest or Database files. Debug Information = None. Strings like I've written above are still shown in the DLL's content.

Comment: That string may come from the `__FILE__` macro. Are you sure you don't use it?

Comment: Found it. It was because of some 'assert' & 'static_assert' calls. Thank you for your answers though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I currently use it has hacks to support sprintf functions which spilled plain-text in compiled binary file. You could now use w_sprintf_s instead of sprintf, like so

```
char test[256] = { 0 };
w_sprintf_s(test, 256, XorStr("test test :D %d %+d\n"), 1, 1337);
```

or use it like this to print stuff on screen for example

```
w_printf(XorStr("test I print this and can't see me inside .dll or .exe"));
```

works on variables, if you have a custom printf() you could use that as well..

```
char szGuid[255] = { 0 };
//generate serial code removed.
char finalSerial[512] = { 0 };
XorCompileTime::w_sprintf(finalSerial, XorStr("serial information=%s"), szGuid);
myprintf(XorStr("Your Hardware ID: %s\n"), szGuid);
```

May add support for wchar_t wide strings like arkan did.. but I have no use for them right now as I don't write anything in symbols / unicode.

Here is a file just rename the code below to a `XorString.h` file and include it in your project simple as that

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstdarg>

#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE( x ) namespace x {
#define END_NAMESPACE }

BEGIN_NAMESPACE(XorCompileTime)

constexpr auto time = __TIME__;
constexpr auto seed = static_cast< int >(time[7]) + static_cast< int >(time[6]) * 10 + static_cast< int >(time[4]) * 60 + static_cast< int >(time[3]) * 600 + static_cast< int >(time[1]) * 3600 + static_cast< int >(time[0]) * 36000;

// 1988, Stephen Park and Keith Miller
// "Random Number Generators: Good Ones Are Hard To Find", considered as "minimal standard"
// Park-Miller 31 bit pseudo-random number generator, implemented with G. Carta's optimisation:
// with 32-bit math and without division

template < int N >
struct RandomGenerator
{
private:
    static constexpr unsigned a = 16807; // 7^5
    static constexpr unsigned m = 2147483647; // 2^31 - 1

    static constexpr unsigned s = RandomGenerator< N - 1 >::value;
    static constexpr unsigned lo = a * (s & 0xFFFF); // Multiply lower 16 bits by 16807
    static constexpr unsigned hi = a * (s >> 16); // Multiply higher 16 bits by 16807
    static constexpr unsigned lo2 = lo + ((hi & 0x7FFF) << 16); // Combine lower 15 bits of hi with lo's upper bits
    static constexpr unsigned hi2 = hi >> 15; // Discard lower 15 bits of hi
    static constexpr unsigned lo3 = lo2 + hi;

public:
    static constexpr unsigned max = m;
    static constexpr unsigned value = lo3 > m ? lo3 - m : lo3;
};

template <>
struct RandomGenerator< 0 >
{
    static constexpr unsigned value = seed;
};

template < int N, int M >
struct RandomInt
{
    static constexpr auto value = RandomGenerator< N + 1 >::value % M;
};

template < int N >
struct RandomChar
{
    static const char value = static_cast< char >(1 + RandomInt< N, 0x7F - 1 >::value);
};

template < size_t N, int K >
struct XorString
{
private:
    const char _key;
    std::array< char, N + 1 > _encrypted;

    constexpr char enc(char c) const
    {
        return c ^ _key;
    }

    char dec(char c) const
    {
        return c ^ _key;
    }

public:
    template < size_t... Is >
    constexpr __forceinline XorString(const char* str, std::index_sequence< Is... >) : _key(RandomChar< K >::value), _encrypted{ enc(str[Is])... }
    {
    }

    __forceinline decltype(auto) decrypt(void)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            _encrypted[i] = dec(_encrypted[i]);
        }
        _encrypted[N] = '\0';
        return _encrypted.data();
    }
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-- Note: XorStr will __NOT__ work directly with functions like printf.
//         To work with them you need a wrapper function that takes a const char*
//         as parameter and passes it to printf and alike.
//
//         The Microsoft Compiler/Linker is not working correctly with variadic 
//         templates!
//  
//         Use the functions below or use std::cout (and similar)!
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

static auto w_printf = [](const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf_s(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_printf_s = [](const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf_s(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_sprintf = [](char* buf, const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

static auto w_sprintf_s = [](char* buf, size_t buf_size, const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf_s(buf, buf_size, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
};

#define XorStr( s ) ( XorCompileTime::XorString< sizeof( s ) - 1, __COUNTER__ >( s, std::make_index_sequence< sizeof( s ) - 1>() ).decrypt() )

END_NAMESPACE
```